# Can Atlassian Bamboo parse multiple test result xmls and present them in the same dashboard

Tags: xml-parsing, automated-tests, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

Pytest results are written out as an xml test report - the job generates 2 xml reports. I have configured an Atlassian bamboo job to parse the report using JUnit parser (available in bamboo). It however only parses the first xml file and ignores the 2nd. Is there a way to parse both and display the test results in the Tests tab of the bamboo job?

Comment: It certainly can. With what expression did you configure the task?

Comment: Adding a single JUnit parser task and selecting the artifact as '*.xml' did not work. I tried creating two JUnit parser tasks, pointed each to read the specific xml file in the bamboo agent build-directory, and, dragged them under 'final' tasks. This seemed to work.  Now the test results from both xmls are parsed.

Comment: This still tells me nothing about the the expression you use. Just paste the exact code. Here's mine that works: `**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml, **/target/jasmine/TEST-jasmine.xml, **/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml`.

Comment: Here are the expressions - tihs is what works for me
`**/Test/file1.xml` and `**/Test/file2.xml`

Comment: Are using comma to separate them? Or do you see any other notable differences from my example?

Comment: I am not using comma to separate them. Notable difference - I created 2 JUnit parser tasks in the job, one for each xml. I could try your way of the comma separated expressions.

Comment: @Alex I tried the comma separated expression that you suggested and it works as well. I have a question - are you able to see the number of 'passed' tests (in green) . In my example I just see the 'new fails', 'existing fails', 'fixed' and 'skipped' tests.

Comment: Yes but only if you click on the job itself. I.e. url is `PROJECT-PLAN-JOB-X` instead of the summary url `PROJECT-PLAN-X`. The former states the green tests count  as `The following X tests have passed: ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although adding separate JUnit parser tasks, one for each xml artifact, a comma separated list of artifacts works as well (answer given by @Alex)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a single JUnit parser task and selecting the artifact as '*.xml' did not work. I tried creating two JUnit parser tasks, pointed each to read the specific xml file in the bamboo agent build-directory, and, dragged them under 'final' tasks. This seemed to work. Now the test results from both xmls are parsed.